# (Define a macro to) facilitate OpenGL command debugging?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, error-handling, compiler-errors

Sometimes it takes a long time of inserting conditional prints and checks to `glGetError()` to narrow down using a form of binary search where the first function call is that an error is first reported by OpenGL.

I think it would be cool if there is a way to build a macro which I can wrap around all GL calls which may fail which will conditionally call `glGetError` immediately after. When compiling for a special target I can have it check `glGetError` with a very high granularity, while compiling for typical release or debug this wouldn't get enabled (I'd check it only once a frame).

Does this make sense to do? Searching for this a bit I find a few people recommending calling `glGetError` after every non-draw gl-call which is basically the same thing I'm describing.

So in this case is there anything clever that I can do (context: I am using GLEW) to simplify the process of instrumenting my gl calls this way? It would be a significant amount of work at this point to convert my code to wrap a macro around each OpenGL function call. What would be great is if I can do something clever and get all of this going without manually determining which are the sections of code to instrument (though that also has potential advantages... but not really. I *really* don't care about performance by the time I'm debugging the source of an error).

Comment: This will (presumably) be done in whatever language you're using to call OpenGL, so we probably need to know that before we can help much (e.g., the answer will probably be different for using Haskell's bindings to OpenGL than if you're using PyOpenGL).

Comment: Ah yes sorry I left that out. I'm hoping for some way to get this done with C++ so that the release code path will remain blazing fast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
void CheckOpenGLError(const char* stmt, const char* fname, int line)
{
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("OpenGL error %08x, at %s:%i - for %s\n", err, fname, line, stmt);
        abort();
    }
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define GL_CHECK(stmt) do { \
            stmt; \
            CheckOpenGLError(#stmt, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        } while (0)
#else
    #define GL_CHECK(stmt) stmt
#endif
```

Use it like this:

```
GL_CHECK( glBindTexture2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id) );
```

If OpenGL function returns variable, then remember to declare it outside of GL_CHECK:

```
const char* vendor;
GL_CHECK( vendor = glGetString(GL_VENDOR) );
```

This way you'll have debug checking if _DEBUG preprocessor symbol is defined, but in "Release" build you'll have just the raw OpenGL calls.

Comment: While it would require me to wrap my existing code with a macro like this I think it will probably be worth it.

Comment: you should wrap the `err = glGetError()` and output in a loop to get all errors from a command, at least if you don't want to just abort

Comment: @ratchetfreak is right. `glGetError should always be called in a loop, until it returns GL_NO_ERROR, if all error flags are to be reset` (from https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetError.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

[`BuGLe`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/index.php) sounds like it will do what you want:

- Dump a textual log of all GL calls made.
- Take a screenshot or capture a video.
- Call `glGetError` after each call to check for errors, and wrap glGetError so that this checking is transparent to your program.
- Capture and display statistics (such as frame rate)
- Force a wireframe mode
- Recover a backtrace from segmentation faults inside the driver, even if the driver is compiled without symbols.

Comment: While this looks really neat already I think a solution to my question which I have control over (and understand) is the better choice at the moment. I look forward to seeing what BuGLe will eventually support.