# why should we put glGetError in a loop?

Tags: opengl

When I search `glGetError`, I find the following (from OpenGL)

> To allow for *distributed implementations*, there may be several *error flag*s.
>   If any single error flag has recorded an error, the value of that flag is returned and that flag is reset to GL_NO_ERROR when glGetError is called.
>   If *more than one* flag has recorded an error, glGetError returns and clears *an arbitrary error flag* value. Thus, glGetError should always be called in a loop, until it returns GL_NO_ERROR, if all error flags are to be reset.

Q1: What is the definitation of **distributed implementation** and **error flag**? and how many of error flags in total?

Q2: what does **arbitrary** mean here?

Q3: "glGetError should always be called in a loop" means this is compulsory in the case of distributed implementation, but if **not**, then we do not need to put glGetError in a loop, right?

Other resources, such as [wrap a macro around `glGetError`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256470/define-a-macro-to-facilitate-opengl-command-debugging), [`glGetError` example in the superbible](http://opengl.czweb.org/ch05/109-114.html), all use a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: What is the definitation of distributed implementation and error flag?

A distributed implementation is when the OpenGL implementation resides on one computer and program making the OpenGL calls on another one. This is not even a obscure, exotic situation, but quite common with X11. Say you can connect with SSH to `example.com` and there's a OpenGL program, say `glxgears`, available there. Then you can execute `glxgears` on `example.com` but have the OpenGL commands being transferred to your local X11 server via the GLX transport.

```
ssh -X example.com glxgears
```

> … and how many of error flags in total?

All the error tokens defined in the OpenGL specification and listed in the `glGetError` reference.

> Q2: what does arbitrary mean here?

Just what the dictionary definition means. If there are several error flags set, the OpenGL specification does not enforce a specific order in which these error flags are reported.

> Q3: "glGetError should always be called in a loop" means this is compulsory in the case of distributed implementation, but if not, then we do not need to put glGetError in a loop, right?

Always call `glGetError` in a loop, because you might end up in a distributed situation without knowing. There's GLX and indirect rendering, but OpenGL may be distributed in any other way, like VirtualGL, or something else, where you don't know what the situation is.

Comment: Things such as `GL_INVALID_ENUM` and  `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` are called *error flag*s?

Comment: @ChanggongZhang: Yes. You actually quoted that in your Q: `… glGetError returns and clears an arbitrary error flag value …`. And if you look at the specification of `glGetError` you'll find the set of values that may be returned, which is the set of error flags.

Comment: Due to my limited knowledge, i fail to understand the example you give on *distributed implementation*. Could you give another example if possible?

Comment: @ChanggongZhang: Well, except for X11/GLX and VirtualGL there are not yet any other practical distributed implementations, so it's a bit difficult to give a practical example. But you may (perfectly valid) think about this way: There may be a network, even the whole Internet between the CPU which executes the program that makes the OpenGL calls, and the GPU that turns these calls into pixels on the screen. And even more interesting with X11/GLX and some tricky hacks it's even possible to have two different computers use the same OpenGL resources (via shared contexts) on the same remote GPU.